# "This many frogs ......." VS "Such a lot of frogs......." VS "So many frogs ......."

Tags: grammar, meaning, idiomatic-language, collocations

**This many frogs out on the slopes does not go unnoticed.** [Frogs race - BBC Earth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-hk1hMMQ0ks) (See:1:20-1:26)

Instead of "this many", I tend to use:

**"Such a lot of frogs ....."**

**"So many frogs ......"**

"Would it be wrong to use them instead of **"this many"**?

Comment: It wouldn't be "wrong", but I suggest Attenborough's *actual* choice of words (probably arrived at by or at least with the help of some very competent and well-paid scriptwriters) is the best choice for the *exact* context. That's because it has greater "immediacy", which perfectly suits a context where we the audience are ***looking*** at a large number of frogs *as he speaks*. (So if you were hoping to be told here that you'd be a better scriptwriter for Attenborough than the team he's already got, you're out of luck! :)

Comment: I could always be mistaken, but my guess is virtually every word that Attenborough says in programs like this has been very precisely scripted. It's nothing like, say, picking holes in "shooting from the lip" utterances from sports commentators, panel game shows, discussion programs, etc.